# I want to update and sum a num paramter to my database... Got Problem... Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, sql-update

I want to Update An Number of goals That a Player Scored so if he socred a goal I want to do an update for his number of goals...
I got an Error in my Code And I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it, please?

## My Asp.net Code:

```
            string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SoccerDataBase.mdb";
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string queryStr = "SELECT Achievement FROM SoccerAchievements WHERE UserID";
        OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AchNums", (SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapt.Fill(ds, "SoccerAchievement");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["SoccerAchievement"].Rows[0];
        int a = int.Parse((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        a = a + int.Parse("@AchNums");
        string query = "UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement= '" + a + "' WHERE UserID";
       sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

## My HTML Code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="SoccerTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="קוד שחקן" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="קבוצות" SortExpression="Team" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Players" HeaderText="שחקנים" 
                SortExpression="Players" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="הישגים">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="AchNums" runat="server"> 
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
                  <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAchNumsFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button class = "AddButton" ID="AddButton" runat="server" onclick="AddButton_Click" Text="עדכן" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

My Problem: Input string was not in the correct format.
[image]

Please help me guys :(

Comment: _Where UserID ??????_ did you miss something here?

Comment: `UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement= '" + a + "' WHERE UserID` => this kind of query is not well-formed (missing `UserID` value) and potentially triggering SQL injection. Better to use parameters instead of concatenating value into query statement.

Comment: UserID Value from my database

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to default to 0 on an empty textbox:

```
int i = string.IsNullOrEmpty((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim()) ? 0 : int.Parse((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
```

If you're looking to default to 0 with any bad formatted input:

```
int i;
if (!int.TryParse((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim(), out i)) i = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex It seems to be like a format exception at the line 
 int a = int.Parse((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());.

In your case, the possibility is that the value return by the textbox is not a valid integer value. Thats why you are getting this error.

Can you try debugging your code and do quickwatch on this statement 'SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAchNumsFooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim()'. Check what you get.

Comment: I am not getting nothing... its not letting me to sum... i want to sum and update a num to a row in my database...

Comment: You are getting error on line 33 which is the step I had mentioned. Code get failed before reaching the SQL statement execution. Error is format exception which means conversion to integer is getting failed. If you check that you could resolve the issue as like answered by @Marvin Klar.